Google Sheets: Multiple conditions for formatting
I was wondering if someone could help me with a conditional formatting formula. Over 4 columns and a number of rows, I would like even rows to be shaded a certain colour, as well as positive and negative values coloured green and red respectively (across all rows).
I am encountering a few issues with this:

If I do this with multiple formulas, the priority mechanism of Google sheets means that I can either have even rows shaded correctly (if I have this formula first) or the text colour will be correct but the shading will not apply, as Google Sheets will not check additional formulas once one has been marked True.

If I try and put this into one formula, using an AND or OR operator, it will either only apply to rows where both conditions are true or it will apply to all rows.


Am I missing a simple solution here? Or is a more complex formula required that I haven't pieced together? Thank you!
Screenshot of the data if this helps at all:


Have you considered using the Alternating Colors shading option within the color palette? you can target specific column ranges.


This solves it, thank you!
